# Мультипотоковый сокет

Tags: java, сокет

Первый раз пишу сокеты на нормальном языке  и вот какие вопросы у меня появились. Раньше я создавал сервер и на каждого клиента у меня создавалась копия серверной логики, что позволяло мне общаться напрямую с каждым клиентом отдельно. Но было это не кодом, а графикой, т.е. нужный функционал я составлял из кубиков, а сам код оставался для меня скрытым. Сам процесс создания копии серверной логики для меня остался не до конца раскрытым.

Можно подробно обычными словами объяснить, что за чем следует. Например, создал я сокет на n порту, первый клиент подключился, как "переместить" его в свою копию логики? Как общаться с каждым клиентом в своём отдельном потоке?

Comment: ну и ещё кое-что   
создал, подключился, как теперь получить данные, не гоняя логику каким-нибудь while который постоянно смотрит не пришли ли данные

Comment: Нужен какой-нибудь событийный фреймворк для сокет-сервера.  
Интересная статья тоже с [Хабры]( http://habrahabr.ru/post/128772/), она конечно про саму идею создания таких фреймворков, но также в ей Вы сможете найти названия уже готовых продуктов для Ява.

Comment: стоит ли этим заниматься ради ~70 клиентов с которых будет просто периодически дёргаться текст?  
я имею ввиду Netty

Comment: Нет, можно за 15 минут сделать сервер, который будет это делать, без всяких спрингов, сервлетов, аплетоа......

Comment: Gorets, очень информативно, а главное аргументированно!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В самом простом случае сервлет слушает порт неблокирующим сокетом. Когда клиент подключается, то сервлет запускает обработку этого сокета в отдельном потоке, а сам начинает снова слушать.
Рекомендую изучить работу на примере простого кода с [Хабры](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69136/).

Answer (score 4):

Где-то наталкивался на хорошую статью, но не могу ее найти сходу. Вот тут есть пример, только не называйте класс с маленькой буквы ;)

[Статья про сокеты с потоками](http://www.kieser.net/linux/java_server.html)

Comment: воо  
другое дело, краткий код и по делу, а то очень раздражает перелопачивать тонну ..... ради 3х строчек кода спрятанных гдето в середине.

Comment: Ссылка протухла.